# Uncaught RangeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Out of memory at ImageData creation

Tags: reactjs, canvas, heatmap

I am using heatmapjs to show multiple heatmap layers. I want to toggle layers dynamically. I have enabled two layers by default. When I run code, whenever heatmap renders I am getting following attached image error

[image]

Comment: I mean, that's a pretty clear error isn't it? It ran out of available memory trying to create a UINT8 array of image data at the size specified. This is either too little memory, or too large a canvas to fit in whatever memory you have...

Comment: Thanks, I will check the memory size.